# WPF: Limit ListBox's height to the height of grid row

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, grid

Here's a part of my XAML:

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
      Margin="10"
      MaxHeight="{Binding Path=ActualHeight,
          RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}">
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>

  <TabControl Grid.Row="0" MinWidth="270" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <TabItem Header="CPU">
      <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
        <ListBox Name="CPUListBox"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding CPUCounters, Mode=OneWay}"
                 SelectionMode="Multiple"
                 MaxHeight="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource
                     AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}, Path=ActualHeight}"
                 BorderThickness="1"
                 BorderBrush="#FF8B8B8B"
                 SelectionChanged="CPUListBox_SelectionChanged"
                 ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
          <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <TextBlock>
                <Run Text="{Binding CounterName, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                <Run Text="{Binding InstanceName, Mode=OneWay}"/>
              </TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
          </ListBox.ItemTemplate>                                
        </ListBox>

        <Grid Name="CPUSelectButtonsGrid">
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

          <Button Grid.Column="0" Name="CPUSelectAllButton"
                  Margin="0,10,0,0"
                  Click="CPUSelectAllButton_Click">
            <TextBlock Text="SELECT ALL"/>
          </Button>
          <Button Grid.Column="1" Name="CPUUnSelectAllButton"
                  Margin="0,10,0,0"
                  Click="CPUUnSelectAllButton_Click">
            <TextBlock Text="UNSELECT ALL"/>
          </Button>
        </Grid>
      </StackPanel>
    </TabItem>

    <TabItem Header="Memory">
      <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <ListBox Name="RAMListBox"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding RAMCounters, Mode=OneWay}"
                 SelectionMode="Multiple"
                 BorderThickness="1"
                 BorderBrush="#FF8B8B8B"
                 SelectionChanged="RAMListBox_SelectionChanged">
          <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <TextBlock>
                <Run Text="{Binding CounterName, Mode=OneWay}" />
                <Run Text="{Binding InstanceName, Mode=OneWay}" />
              </TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
          </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>

        <Grid Name="RAMSelectButtonsGrid">
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

          <Button Grid.Column="0" Name="RAMSelectAllButton"
                  Margin="0,10,0,0"
                  Click="RAMSelectAllButton_Click" >
            <TextBlock Text="SELECT ALL"/>
          </Button>
          <Button Grid.Column="1" Name="RAMUnSelectAllButton"
                  Margin="0,10,0,0"
                  Click="RAMUnSelectAllButton_Click" >
            <TextBlock Text="UNSELECT ALL"/>
          </Button>
        </Grid>
      </StackPanel>
    </TabItem>
  </TabControl>

  <StackPanel Grid.Row="1"
              Orientation="Horizontal"
              HorizontalAlignment="Right"
              Margin="0,15,6,0">
    <TextBlock Name="NumberOfSelectionsTextBlock" Text ="0"/>
    <TextBlock Text=" items selected"/>
  </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Here' what's wrong:
I have a `ListBox` in each tab of `TabControl`. When the number of elements in a `ListBox` is big, the `ListBox` covers the buttons and I can't get access to them. I tried limitting `ListBox`'s `Height` to `MaxHeight="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}, Path=ActualHeight}"`, but it's too much - it takes `Height` of the whole `Grid`, also covering the `Buttons` and `TextBoxes` below them. I'd like the whole thing to be dynamically resized with the `Window`, so that nothing gets cut off.

I can't find a proper solution to this. What should I do?

Comment: can you show me an image of how exactly does it cover the buttons?

Comment: why not use a grid instead of stack panel and give button row fixed height and rest to list ?

Comment: @Muds - that fixed my problem. Thank you very much. If you add your solution as an answer, I'll check it as the correct one. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is your stack panel that grows when no of items grow. A better layout would be to use a WPF `Grid` where you can have two rows.
Second row will contain Buttons and that row can then be given fixed size where as the first row can be set as `Width = *`

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
</Grid>
```